# How to create a scheduler job in oracle 11g with time window

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduler

how to create a scheduler job for stored procedure which will run every seconds but only from monday till friday and  10 to 20 clock?

Comment: You really what a job to run every second?  It must be a pretty fast task.

Comment: yes, i want to read the exchange prices over tcp ip

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relaunching a job every second it would make more sense to have a permanent background task which polls the relevant table once per second.  Use `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(1)` to achieve the necessary wait.  (Access to DBMS_LOCK is not granted by default so you will need a DBA to grant execute privileges to your user.)

Comment: i will try tomorrow a procedure with the continuous loop which will end for given time. this one will be started once a day. I expect a lot of data per second, so it should not come to wait. I do not query the table, but have a tcp ip connection. so i thought to  relaunch when the connection will get lost.